# How to properly share code between client/server using swagger/openapi

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, fastapi

I'm trying to figure out how to use openapi-generator to to minimize duplicate python code between the client and server.  If it matters, I'm using FastAPI as my web framework along with Pydantic.

On the server side, I have:

```
class Member(BaseModel):
    name: str
    def greeting(self):
        return "Hello " + name
```

I can then write:

```
m1 = Member("John Doe")
print(m1.greeting())
```

So far so good from the server perspective.

In FastAPI, I then create an API

```
@app.get("/members/", response_model=List[Member])
def get_members():
    m1 = Member("Jane Doe")
    m2 = Member("John Smith")
    return [m1, m2]
```

After I generate client code using `openapi-generator`, I can then write:
`my_members = my_api.get_members()` on the client side.  Everything works great up until this point.

Now, however, is where the problem hits. I want to call `my_members[0].greeting()`
on the client, but this is not available in the client library that `openapi-generator` generated. It doesn't generate any helper functions which means I have to come up with a more complex way of sharing data structures and methods between the client and the server.

Am I wrong to think of code sharing this way? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Have you found any documentation that tells you can share specific code implementation through `openapi-generator`. What would you want to happen if you have platform specific dependent code, or language specific library (e.g. numpy in Python). I do not think it is possible.

Comment: I haven't found any docs related to this, although I am a novice with openapi-generator. 
  For the client stubs generated for the same language as the server language (in my case Python), it would be nice to just pass the helper functions through to the code generated for the client.  Or if that won't work, perhaps someone can recommend a better way to organize my code so that I can generate the same helper functions on both the client and server.  It seems like a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenApi will only allow you to specify an object's data, not functions.

To share common code between the client and the server you can create a third project/module with the common code.

Then use it as a dependency in your client/server projects.

```
─ myapp
   ├── client
   │   └── __init__.py
   ├── server
   │   └── __init__.py
   └── common
       └── __init__.py
```